# Manipulation of one electromagnetic field by another

Tags: electric-fields

How is it possible for one electromagnetic field to alter, or control, another electromagnetic field.  I am thinking specifically of manipulation of the endogenous fields that are related to brain function by externally applied exogenous fields.  The endogenous fields are typically very low-frequency electric fields that are characterized as being near-field; therefore, they are reactive, non-propagating fields.  Nevertheless, they can be measured spatially and temporally at the exterior of the skull and do provide meaningful information as to brain function.  My question is, "Does a mathematical theory exist for describing the interaction of endogenous and exogenous fields, or, more generally, for describing the alteration of one field in the presence of the other?"

Comment: I'm no doctor, so I must ask: You say the endogenous fields can be measured at the exterior of the skull. I assume you mean the measuring device is in contact with the animal. Can the fields be measured if the measuring device is not in physical contact with the animal but, say, within a millimeter from being in contact? If not, then it probably isn't the electric fields that are measured, but more likely a transferred charge or potential at the point of measurement. In this case, it may be impossible to selectively manipulate those fields without altering all electric activity in the brain

Comment: But as I said, I'm no doctor

Comment: I always thought the external magnetic field affected ion movement between the synapses.  Charged ions won't move in a straight line in a powerful external magnetic field which can disrupt electrochemical signals.  If neurons can't communicate across the chemical gaps then that region of the brain is effectively shut off.

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic fields of different sources do not change each other directly; if a source was not altered by the presence of the other field, its field would remain the same.

That being said, every source (charged particle) responds to external electromagnetic field by changing its velocity. This may not be visible effect macroscopically, but it may have the consequence that the electromagnetic field of the particle changes more intensively and in a different way than it would without presence of the external field.

So indirectly, external field does influence the field of the source, via proxy - acting on the source itself.

For example, when radio receiver is close to radio emitter (e.g. radio broadcasting antenna), the function of the emitter is influenced by it and the electromagnetic field *of the emitter* is different than it would be if the receiver was far away.

It is reasonable to assume the same happens with EM field of brain. If you put some physical body close to brain, the parts of the brain emitting EM field will experience other EM field of the body and as a response their EM field will be altered.